# Webfont font-face does not change font of html elements, although style is updated

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I installed a web font from myfonts.com on my WordPress site. I updated the CSS as follows:

```
@import url("../bridge/style.css");

/* LICENSE HERE */

@import url("//hello.myfonts.net/count/xxxxxxx");

@font-face {
    font-family: "VeneerTwo";
    src: url('http://www.example.com/wordpress/webfonts/xxxxxx_0_0.eot');
    src: url('http://www.example.com/wordpress/webfonts/xxxxxx_0_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype');
    src: url('http://www.example.com/wordpress/webfonts/xxxxxx_0_0.woff2') format('woff2');
    src: url('http://www.example.com/wordpress/webfonts/xxxxxx_0_0.woff') format('woff');
    src: url('http://www.example.com/wordpress/webfonts/xxxxxx_0_0.ttf') format('truetype');
    src: url('http://www.example.com/wordpress/webfonts/xxxxxx_0_0.svg#wf') format('svg');
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 { font-family: "VeneerTwo" !important; }
```

All the fonts exist on the webserver.

When I check the site in Developer Tools I see that the H2 element has the style `VeneerTwo`:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 {
    font-family: "VeneerTwo" !important;
}
```

Unfortunately, the font of the `h2` element is just the default (Times New Roman if I am not mistaken).

Does anyone know why the VeneerTwo font is not displayed and how it can be fixed?

Comment: I'm not sure if h2 having a bold weight has something to do with it.

Comment: In your developer console, what does it say in the section of the _computed_ style rules actually applied? And in your http servers access log, are those font files actually requested at all?

Comment: @urben Can you provide a working (or, well, non-working) example , for intance in jsfiddle or something, that we can take a look at?

Comment: @MrLister Here is the JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z7chm395/

For now I changed the urls to the fonts for safety, but with working urls it had the same result as mentioned in the opening post.

Comment: @arkascha Computed style is `font-family: "VeneerTwo";
: style.css:54;
: h2 "VeneerTwo";`. And access_logs shows the fonts are not requested unless it is on an iPhone.

`(iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_0_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13A452 Safari/601.1" www.xxxxx.nl`

Comment: @urben The fonts in the fiddle don't exist. _Of course_ the fiddle displays the page in the browser's default! So that's no good. Give an example with real fonts. Also, the URL you used for the non-existing fonts, ehm.

Comment: @MrLister I tried to say it also does not work with real fonts using the real URL which I am not sure if I can post here because we paid for the fonts. I could not find other working fonts on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the @font-face first, before you import other media or css.

Comment: @import must be on top.

Comment: Sometimes this is a browser bug where font-face must be before import. I don't know why, once this happened to me and this is what i did.

Answer (score 0):

But you told that the font is displayed on the developers tool , just try to clear the cache and try again .. Like by pressing ctrl+f5 twice

Comment: What different is that to what the OP already does? Apart from removing the `!important`?

Comment: Sorry, but programming is not a guessing game. This is nonsense. If you have no idea what the issue is, then you should not post an "answer".

Comment: I put my suggestions for the answer and the person with the above question can just take the suggestion or leave it .... Keep Calm

Comment: I am more than calm, don't worry. But as said: this is not an answer. What difference should it make? This is like giving the hint to use blue ink instead of black for your invoices because then you get more money payed. Please delete this "answer" to prevent that you get further down voted. Thanks!

Comment: Sure I agree with your request

Answer (score 0):

I want to add the following: 
Motivated by the suggestion of @arkascha to check the access logs I just checked it with an old iphone I had layin around (iPhone 4). And yes, on the iPhone 4 the font is being displayed.